# Moving speed like keypress event

Tags: javascript, three.js

i try to explain my problem the best i can.
I have a pacman game where i move the pacman with the keyboard, the pacman moves a constant unit in every direction i check colision based on a map that i defined previously where the "-" are the obstacles, now i want to create the enemys, and i want that the enemys move randomnly without the keypress of course, the thing is that with the keypress the speed control is controlled, but with the random move i cant assure that the enemy moves like it pressed by the keyboard i want to controll the framerate here i am using requestAnimationFrame i tried the frame controll but didnt work here is my code:

```
   function handleKeyPressed(e) {

   var PacMan = scene.getObjectByName('PacMan');
   gameSong.play();
   switch(String.fromCharCode(e.which))
   {
     case "w": if(!detectaColisao(PacMan.position.x, PacMan.position.y + SCALE))
          PacMan.position.y += SCALE;
       break;
     case "a": if(!detectaColisao(PacMan.position.x - SCALE, PacMan.position.y))
         PacMan.position.x -= SCALE;
       break;
     case "s": if(!detectaColisao(PacMan.position.x, PacMan.position.y - SCALE))
         PacMan.position.y -= SCALE;
       break;
     case "d": if(!detectaColisao(PacMan.position.x + SCALE, PacMan.position.y))
         PacMan.position.x += SCALE;
       break;

   }
}

    function anima()
{
  var delta=clock.getDelta();
  orbitCamera.update(delta);

  requestAnimationFrame(anima);
  rendere
```

Comment: Please define " didnt work ".

Comment: the first time i defined the random move, it moves in  position.x like 10 but it moves everytime, if i defined it with a setTimeout inside the animationframe it doesnt work to i want to cotrol the frames

Answer (score 0):

> it moves in position.x like 10 but it moves everytime

Do you mean that it moves too many times before the animation gets handled?

The reason for that is that keypressed is asyncronous from your render loop - it happens whenever a key is held down, which is constant for as long as you have a key held down.

What you have to do is to only move your pacman once per animate() cycle.

so what I would change is this-  don't move the pacman within your keypressed function, but instead trigger some booleans that will then move your pacman within the animate() cycle, like so:

```
var u, d, l, r;
u = d = l = r = false;

function handleKeyPressed(e) {
  switch (String.fromCharCode(e.which)) {
    case "w":
      u = true;
      break;
    case "a":
      l = true;
      break;
    case "s":
      d = true;
      break;
    case "d":
      r = true;
      break;
  }
}

function handleKeyReleased(e) {
  switch (String.fromCharCode(e.which)) {
    case "w":
      u = false;
      break;
    case "a":
      l = false;
      break;
    case "s":
      d = false;
      break;
    case "d":
      r = false;
      break;
  }
}

function moveModel(_u, _d, _l, _r, obj) {
  if (_u && !detectaColisao(obj.position.x, obj.position.y + SCALE)) {
    obj.position.y += SCALE;
  }
  if (_d && !detectaColisao(obj.position.x, obj.position.y + SCALE)) {
    obj.position.y -= SCALE;
  }
  if (_l && !detectaColisao(obj.position.x, obj.position.y + SCALE)) {
    obj.position.x -= SCALE;
  }
  if (_r && !detectaColisao(obj.position.x, obj.position.y + SCALE)) {
    obj.position.x += SCALE;
  }
}

function anima() {
  var PacMan = scene.getObjectByName('PacMan');
  moveModel(u, d, l, r, PacMan);
  var delta = clock.getDelta();
  orbitCamera.update(delta);
  requestAnimationFrame(anima);
  rendere();
}
```

Note that you also need to turn those booleans back off again when the key gets released, so we add another handleKeyReleased to catch when this happens. and we do the opposite of the handleKeyPressed function.

So the reason you need to add this layer of abstraction is that the keypressed event happens whenever it happens, and it doesn't care where in the animation cycle you are. But we only want to move once per animate cycle, so rather than move it directly, we create a series of flags that tell the model if and how it should move.

Comment: the problem is not exactly that, maybe i didnt explained well, the problem is not with the pacman, but with the enemys that i am creating, my pacman moves 10 units evertyme when i press key, its fine, and i handle colisions checking in a matrix where it colides directly. with my enemies i want the same approach but randomly, without keypess i want to give a random position but i dont know how to handle position animate because it becomes to fast and if i give him a lower value then 10 i cant check colisions correctly, the enemys.position increment must be 10 but the framerate must be different

Comment: i think i explained well, but i can explain better in PM if you can ofc

Answer (score 0):

Ah okay that makes sense. So maybe you can add a value to their userData, some variable like "ghost.userData.timer" then every cycle you add 1 to it. When it goes past some coolDown variable that you define, like 60, then you give them a random move and set timer back to 0.

That way they'll take steps at regular intervals that you define.